# cronjob starting php web application

Tags: php, cron, web

I have a php web application doing an import. I open the page click on import and off it goes.
It does all sort of checking before it save the result in the database.

Now I want to do this daily automatically. How?

A cronjob starts only php scripts, but can I start an application with it?

To be more specific:
I have a presentation layer, controller and a DAO.
For the cronjob the presentation layer is irrelevant.

What I actually need to start is a function in the controller. This import function gets from amazon a s3 bucket list, cross-checks with existing entries in the database and saves the new ones to the database using the DAO. I'm also using 2 other objects. 
So to extract the code and put it in a script would be really an overkill. Also because I have 4 different imports.

With wget I dont understand how to pass the right click to the cronjob. I have on that page 4 buttons to start 4 different imports. I'm using a javascript function onclick="submitImport('importTranscripts')" and a form:

```
<form name="form1" id="importForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How does the link have to look like?

Comment: Why do you need start application if everything done in php?

Comment: If you want to do this the right way you should abstract the code that does the import out of you application and make it callable from a commandline php script, that way you avoid the overhead of HTTP when running this in a cron, might be overkill in your situation though, but it's a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use wget in your cron job.  E.g

```
wget -O- http://example.com/yourscript.php
```

Comment: How does the link have to look like when I have a form and want to pass the parameter in POST?

Comment: For reaching to that import page I have to pass a login.
Is it possible with wget?